# How do I specify multiple ranges of columns in an Excel VBA for loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA for loop in the form:    For col = 23 to 27 
where the range 23 to 27 refers to columns 'W' to 'AA'. I now want to add more distinct ranges to the For loop so that it will loop through 23 to 27, then 30 to 33, then 40 to 44, etc. What is a way in which I can do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you tell all the ranges you're referring? I can't see any obvious pattern here

Comment: There is not really a pattern to the ranges I require, I just need a way to do the union of all the ranges. I can't use the Union() function because my "ranges" aren't strictly ranges like expected by VBA. Any other options other then having to write multiple for loops?

Comment: You can list all the address of the ranges into an array and loop through every element of it

Comment: That is also an option, I was hoping for some kind of a union of ranges but I'll probably just opt for that. Thanks!

Comment: `For Each col in Range("W:AA,AD:AG").Columns`

Comment: @TimWilliams - `For Each col in Range("W:AA,AD:AG").Columns` would actually have to be `For Each colRng in Range("W:AA,AD:AG").Columns` `col = colRng.Column` (unless the OP changes `col` to be a range instead of a number, which may be a desirable thing to do anyway).

Comment: @YowE3K - yes, `col` is a range here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd loop through the columns which are stored in an array.

```
Dim arrCol(1 to 3, 1 to 2)
Dim i As Integer

'Initialize array
arrCol(1,1) = 23
arrCol(1,2) = 27
arrCol(2,1) = 30
arrCol(2,2) = 33
arrCol(3,1) = 40
arrCol(3,2) = 44

'Loop through column ranges
For i = 1 to UBound(arrCol())
    Range(Columns(arrCol(i,1)),Columns(arrCol(i,2))).SomeStatement
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Select Case statement:

```
For col = 23 to 999 'or whatever
    Select Case col
        Case 23 To 27, 30 To 33, 40 To 44
            'do whatever you like here
    End Select
Next
```